# Working with nested matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

But each its element, itself, is another matrix too.

```
a={{0,1,1},{0,1,0}}
b={{0,0,1},{1,0,0}}

c={{0,0,0},{0,1,0}}
d={{0,0,1},{1,0,1}}
```

I want to comprise 'a' and 'b' with their elements; and respectively 'c' and 'd'. If just one element be similar in 'a' and 'b' and simultaneously equal to '1', (here:)

```
a13=b13=1
```

the 'b' element of  'A' must be replaced with zero. (here A12=0).

Question1:
For the comparison I write bellow line, I Do not know which must be written in the A['indexes referring to location of b'] in this line:

```
Do[If[a[[i, j]] == b[[k, m]], A['indexes referring to location of b'] = 0], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1,3}, {k, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 3}]
```

Question2:
All of us know each element of a matrix has two indexes {i and j; for example Aij}. are there any possibility to devote four indexes to a one element of a Matrix(for example Aijkm? Actually, if we can devote four indexes to each A element in the above 'Do' loop, the line will be written more easily.

Question3: 
if instead of 'a','b', 'c' and 'd' we have numerics:

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

Are the any possibility to devote a matrix to numeric!!!!!!?

For example

```
1={{0,1,1},{0,1,0}}
2={{0,0,1},{1,0,0}}
```

!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract those matrices. I've replaced `0`s with `2` in the second so `0 - 2` won't give `0`.

```
If[
   FreeQ[# - (#2 /. (0) -> 2), 0, {2}],
   {##},
   {#, 0}
   ] & @@@ A
```

> ```
> {
>    {{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0}, 
>    {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}}
>   }
> ```

---

For the second part if those matrice are associated with numbers:

```
B = MapThread[List, {A, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, 2]
```

> [image]

```
If[
   FreeQ[#[[ 1]] - (#2[[ 1]] /. (0) -> 2), 0, {2}],
   {##}[[ ;; , 2]],
   {#[[2]], 0}
   ] & @@@ B
```

> ```
> {{1, 0}, {3, 4}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But Where is 'a'. As it shown, 'b' remained and 'a' eliminated. I wanted the vise versa process

Comment: No problem, But the major one in your answer is: I could not make the matrix:       {{a, 0}, {c, d}} in the result of your code!!

Comment: The result of the second one as you write, is {{1}, {3, 4}} How can I get a Zero besides '1'? I mean, the result become same as: {{1, 0}, {3, 4}}

Comment: @mostafa done. please, hold on with an accept a day or two and accept the answer which fits you needs the best :) Early accept may discourage others.

Comment: Kuba,I read some Mathematica documentation but I confused in translation of this line:    If[FreeQ[#-(#2/.(0)→2),0,{2}],{##},{#,0}]&"@@@" A   I think I could not deeply understand what happens in this line completely, because I am not able to generalize this process to a 3*3 matrix in which must be a possibility for comparison A13 with A11.

Comment: Actually I could not recognize the difference between # and #2, what are referred by these ones in the main matric. Also I could not understand the effect of True or False in IF statement.

Comment: @mostafa I'm sorry, I was afk, I will answer your tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mostafa are you able to join this room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14856/temp

Comment: I'm sorry. Unfortunately, I was not in connection (on-line) that time. I hope in the future to be on line with you, simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

The question as it stands is nearly indecipherable. Please, make an effort to better explain what you're trying to do, with *complete* examples, e.g., of inputs and expected outputs at least.

The question itself should not be a puzzle to readers...

That said, I *think* this is what your asking for (if not, comment, I'll happily delete).

Part 1:

"In my 2x2 matrix, where each element is itself a 2X3 matrix of zeroes and ones, compare the elements in each row of the 2X2 matrix, and if the second element has a one corresponding to the same position in the first element, make it zero":

```
a = {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}
b = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}

c = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}
d = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}

aa = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

aa[[All, 2]] = BitXor[aa[[All, 2]], BitAnd @@@ aa];

aa

(*
{{{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}, 
 {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}}}
*)
```

Note I used `aa` for the full matrix instead of `A`. It is generally a *bad idea* to use uppercase symbols/initials: you might interfere with a built-in symbol, leading to at the very least confusion.

Second part:

Of course. Read the documentatation. E.g., here's one 4 indices "deep":

```
fourDims = Array[#1*#2*#3*#4 &, {2, 3, 2, 2}]
Depth@fourDims
fourDims[[2, 3, 1, 1]]

(*

{{{{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 8}}, {{3, 6}, {6, 12}}}, 
 {{{2, 4}, {4, 8}}, {{4, 8}, {8, 16}}, {{6, 12}, {12, 24}}}}

6

*)
```

Part 3:
Yes, you can use, for example, rules to accomplish this:

```
aa = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
aa /. {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d}

(*

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

{{{{0,1,1},{0,1,0}},{{0,0,1},{1,0,0}}},{{{0,0,0},{0,1,0}},{{0,0,1},{1,0,1}}}}

*)
```

Note the end result is precisely the same as the definition of `aa` above. The second list simply applies rules to transform the numeric entries into the desired components a,b,c... Read the documentation re: `Rules` for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and answers. OK, next I will try to explain more obviously. This example is near to the main question with which I am challenging. I am trying with your help and other skillful persons here to solve it step by step. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}
b = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
c = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}
d = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}

aA = {{a, b}, {c, d}}


If[Or @@ Join @@ MapThread[#1 == #2 != 0 &, {##}, 2], {#, 0}, {##}] & @@@ aA
```

or

```
aA[[All, 2]] = If[Or @@ Join @@ MapThread[#1 == #2 != 0 &, {##}, 2], 0, #] & @@@ aA; aA
```

both give

```
(* {{{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},   0}, 
     {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}}} *)
```